# Spacing between branches of trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I am having problems with spacing between branches in the following tree:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} %vector art
\usetikzlibrary{snakes, matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
% Two node styles for game trees: solid and hollow
solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=white}
}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize,
 level 1/.style={level distance=10mm,sibling distance=30mm},
 level 2/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=10mm},
 level 3/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=10mm}
]
% The Tree
\node(0)[solid node,label=above:{\textbf{Start}}]{} 
child{node(1)[hollow node]{$L$}
child{[black] node(11)[hollow node]{}}
child{[black] node(12)[hollow node]{}}
edge from parent node[left]{$p$}
}
child{node(2)[hollow node]{$H$}
child{[black] node(41)[hollow node, ]{}}
child{[black] node(42)[hollow node,]{}}
edge from parent node[right]{$1-p$}
};
% information set
\draw[dashed,bend right](11)to(12);
\draw[dashed,bend right](41)to(42);


\path (11) -- node (H) {$x_{1}$} (12);
\path (41) -- node {$y_{1}$} (42);


% scope env to locally redefine level 1 style
%\begin{scope}[
%  level 1/.style={sibling distance=10mm}
%]
\node(00)[below=4mm,hollow node] at (H) {$H$}
child{ node[hollow node] {}
          edge from parent node[left] {$A$}
}
child{ node[solid node, label=right:{\textbf{Start 2}}] {} 
child{node(3)[hollow node]{$L$}
child{[black] node(66)[hollow node, ]{}}
child{[black] node(77)[hollow node, ]{}}
edge from parent node[left]{$p$}
}
child{node(5)[hollow node]{$H$}
child{[black] node(6)[hollow node, ]{}}
child{[black] node(7)[hollow node, ]{}}
edge from parent node[right]{$1-p$}
}
edge from parent node[right] {$R$}
}
;
%New info set
\draw[dashed,bend right](6)to(7);
\draw[dashed,bend right](66)to(77);
\path (6) -- node (HH){$r_{2}$} (7);
\path (66) -- node (HL){$z_{2}$} (77);
\node(000)[below=4mm,hollow node] at (HH) {$L$}
child{ node[hollow node, label=below:{$\{U_{i}(c_{i1},c_{i2},0,g_{2})\}_{i=H,L}$}] {} 
          edge from parent node[left] {$A$}
}
child{ node[hollow node, label=below:{$\{U_{i}(c_{i1},c_{i1},0,0)\}_{i=H,L}$}] {} 
edge from parent node[right] {$R$}
}
;
\node(0000)[below=4mm,hollow node] at (HL) {$H$}
child{ node[hollow node, label=below:{$\{U_{i}(c_{i1},c_{i2},0,g_{2})\}_{i=H,L}$}] {} 
          edge from parent node[left] {$A$}
}
child{ node[hollow node, label=below:{$\{U_{i}(c_{i1},c_{i1},0,0)\}_{i=H,L}$}] {} 
edge from parent node[right] {$R$}
}
;
%\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I have tried to use scope so I could have local environments well-defined, and that solves the spacing problem, but at the cost of not being able to build child nodes in the way I want it:
[image]

Anyone has a good idea on how to "fix" this spacing issue I am facing with this tree? Thank you.

Comment: This is a common problem with the standard TikZ tree methods. Better to use `forest` or `tikz-qtree` or the newer `istgame` package (for drawing game trees).  [What is a more efficient way to draw this tree?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/113315)

Comment: I will give it a try. Thank you @AlanMunn. Any ways to solve this in the environment I have it above?

Comment: The thing is that Forest will space it for you. Otherwise, you have to do it. (Never used `istgame`, so don't know about that one.) If this is the only tree you need to draw, fair enough. Otherwise, it will be worth your while to learn a more powerful package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend one of the more specialized tree drawing packages for doing this. `forest` or `istgame` might be most appropriate.

To do this manually you could could add explicit sibling distances for the L and H nodes that branch from Start 2:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} %vector art
\usetikzlibrary{snakes, matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
% Two node styles for game trees: solid and hollow
solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=white}
}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize,
 level 1/.style={level distance=10mm,sibling distance=30mm},
 level 2/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=10mm},
 level 3/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=10mm}
]
% The Tree
\node(0)[solid node,label=above:{\textbf{Start}}]{} 
child{node(1)[hollow node]{$L$}
child{[black] node(11)[hollow node]{}}
child{[black] node(12)[hollow node]{}}
edge from parent node[left]{$p$}
}
child{node(2)[hollow node]{$H$}
child{[black] node(41)[hollow node, ]{}}
child{[black] node(42)[hollow node,]{}}
edge from parent node[right]{$1-p$}
};
% information set
\draw[dashed,bend right](11)to(12);
\draw[dashed,bend right](41)to(42);


\path (11) -- node (H) {$x_{1}$} (12);
\path (41) -- node {$y_{1}$} (42);


% scope env to locally redefine level 1 style
%\begin{scope}[
%  level 1/.style={sibling distance=10mm}
%]
\node(00)[below=4mm,hollow node] at (H) {$H$}
child{ node[hollow node] {}
          edge from parent node[left] {$A$}
}
child{ node[solid node, label=right:{\textbf{Start 2}}] {} 
child[sibling distance=2.25in]{node(3)[hollow node]{$L$}
child{[black] node(66)[hollow node, ]{}}
child{[black] node(77)[hollow node, ]{}}
edge from parent node[left]{$p$}
}
child[sibling distance=2.25in]{node(5)[hollow node]{$H$}
child{[black] node(6)[hollow node, ]{}}
child{[black] node(7)[hollow node, ]{}}
edge from parent node[right]{$1-p$}
}
edge from parent node[right] {$R$}
}
;
%New info set
\draw[dashed,bend right](6)to(7);
\draw[dashed,bend right](66)to(77);
\path (6) -- node (HH){$r_{2}$} (7);
\path (66) -- node (HL){$z_{2}$} (77);
\node(000)[below=4mm,hollow node] at (HH) {$L$}
child{ node[hollow node, label=below:{$\{U_{i}(c_{i1},c_{i2},0,g_{2})\}_{i=H,L}$}] {} 
          edge from parent node[left] {$A$}
}
child{ node[hollow node, label=below:{$\{U_{i}(c_{i1},c_{i1},0,0)\}_{i=H,L}$}] {} 
edge from parent node[right] {$R$}
}
;
\node(0000)[below=4mm,hollow node] at (HL) {$H$}
child{ node[hollow node, label=below:{$\{U_{i}(c_{i1},c_{i2},0,g_{2})\}_{i=H,L}$}] {} 
          edge from parent node[left] {$A$}
}
child{ node[hollow node, label=below:{$\{U_{i}(c_{i1},c_{i1},0,0)\}_{i=H,L}$}] {} 
edge from parent node[right] {$ROO$}
}
;
%\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: That is a beauty, @AlanMunn. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to use the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package. With this package you can use `\xtdistance{<lev dist>}{<sib dist>}` to change the level and sibling distances.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}   

\begin{istgame}[scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize]
\tikzset{oval node/.style={ellipse node,minimum size=1pt,inner sep=1pt}}
\xtShowEndPoints[oval node]
% The Tree
\xtdistance{10mm}{30mm}
\istroot(S)
  \istb{p}[al]  \istb{1-p}[ar]  \endist
\xtOwner(S){\textbf{Start}} % owner
\xtdistance{15mm}{10mm}
\istrooto(L)(S-1){L}
  \istb  \istb  \endist
\istrooto(H)(S-2){H}
  \istb  \istb  \endist
\xtInfoset[bend right,dashed](L-1)(L-2){$x_1$}[centered]
\xtInfoset[bend right,dashed](H-1)(H-2){$y_1$}[centered]
\xtdistance{10mm}{25mm}
\istrooto(00)([yshift=-18mm]L){H}
  \istb{A}[l]  \istb{R}[r]  \endist
% The Tree: Start 2
\xtdistance{10mm}{50mm}
\istroot(S2)(00-2)
  \istb{p}[al]  \istb{1-p}[ar]  \endist
\xtOwner(S2){\textbf{\ Start 2}}[right]
\xtdistance{15mm}{10mm}
\istrooto(L2)(S2-1){L}
  \istb  \istb  \endist
\istrooto(H2)(S2-2){H}
  \istb  \istb  \endist
\xtInfoset[bend right,dashed](L2-1)(L2-2){$z_2$}[centered]
\xtInfoset[bend right,dashed](H2-1)(H2-2){$r_2$}[centered]
\xtdistance{10mm}{25mm}
\istrooto(HH)([yshift=-18mm]L2){H}
  \istb{A}[l]{\{U_{i}(c_{i1},c_{i2},0,g_{2})\}_{i=H,L}}
  \istb{ROO}[r]{\{U_{i}(c_{i1},c_{i1},0,0)\}_{i=H,L}}
  \endist
\istrooto(LL)([yshift=-18mm]H2){L}
  \istb{A}[l]{\{U_{i}(c_{i1},c_{i2},0,g_{2})\}_{i=H,L}}
  \istb{R}[r]{\{U_{i}(c_{i1},c_{i1},0,0)\}_{i=H,L}}
  \endist
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```